# I want to use Railsnstaller Do I have to do anything different if I have Git already installed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I downloaded railsinstaller and it asks me for my name and address for Git. I already have git installed. Will filling in this info screw up my Git or will it recognize I have a Git connection already? Do I have to do anything different if I have Git already installed?

Comment: address for git? do you mean path for git binary? which operating system do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can just copy the information you have in your `~/.gitconfig` file ?

Comment: I went ahead and filled out the same info I had for my Github and it all turned out fine. Thanks for the help!